# How to fetch previous month's data from database in php?

Tags: php, date, mysqli

I am developing a php website and need to fetch some data from previous month. Not only first previous month but last five months data. And I am confused that how can I do this? In my database I've created two columns. One is "Month" and another is "Year". So row will look like

---

id ----  text ---- month ---- year

1  ----  hello ---- May ----- 2014

2  ----  hi ----  May  ----- 2014

---

Now I can fetch data by using date() function like this.

```
$first_month = date('F', strtotime('-1 month'));
$second_month = date('F', strtotime('-2 month'));
$third_month = date('F', strtotime('-3 month'));
```

for five months, I can create five variables. But for year? I mean if current month is january and year 2014, then I will need to fetch data from December 2013, so how it will work? Can anyone suggest me?

I am so confused. Please tell me if anyone has done something like this before. I need idea or concept.

Comment: To future explorers.  This breaks convention, and disallows use of native wrappers and helper functions, such as easy `SELECTS`, changing time-zones, and ordering.  It is highly advised not to do this.  Make use of the built-in MySQL type `date`, it will save many a headache.

Answer (score 1):

You could either restructure your tables to use a Unix timestamp or MySQL `date`, and select using comparator's. Or you could create temporary tables and do the same.

The direction you are heading will be nontrivial to maintain and debug. Also, the correct queries will be more complex than I believe you expect them to be. For instance, spanning years will be one line with the above. While many many lines going the way you are.

**Edit:** To maintain your current logic, the SQL Select statement would have to be a series of `WHERE`s.  For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
    (month IN ('April', 'May') AND year = 2014)
```

Would select the months of April and May in the year 2014.

The following would span a year:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
    (month IN ('December') AND year = 2013)
OR
    (month IN ('January') AND year = 2014)
```

From a programmatic standpoint, you would need to generate an array of years and months, including all months of the year you would like to select from.

The structure for such an array would look like such:

```
// For the first example
$where1 = array(
    2014 => array(
        'April',
        'May'
    )
);

// For the second example
$where2 = array(
    2013 => array(
        'December'
    ),
    2014 => array(
        'January'
    )
);
```

And you would have to create a `WHERE` clause from those arrays.  Such as:

```
/**
 * Outputs
 * [where1] (month IN ('April', 'May') AND year = 2014)
 *
 * [where2] (month IN ('December') AND year = 2013) OR (month IN ('January') AND year = 2014)
 */
foreach(array('where1','where1') as $where_name) {

    $clause = '';

    $where = $$where_name;

    $wheres = array();

    foreach($where as $year => $months) {
        $wheres[] = "month IN ('" . implode("', '", $months) . "') AND year = $year";
    }

    $clause = '('.implode (') OR (', $wheres).')';

    echo "[$where_name] $clause\n\n";
}
```

That should do the trick.  There is a working example [here](http://ideone.com/UWI5wI).  Gathering the list of months is almost the same as you have been doing, but moreso like so:

```
    list($month, $year) = explode(" ", date('F Y', strtotime('-3 month')));

var_dump($month); // February
var_dump($year); // 2014

$array[$year][] = $month; // Will create the array structure as above
```

There are more efficient ways, but this is the general idea.  I believe I have left you with some interesting tools to solve your problem.

To make this hit a range you would need to do something along the lines of:

```
$where3 = array();

for ($prev_months = 1; $prev_months <= 5; $prev_months++) {
    list($month, $year) = explode(" ", date('F Y', strtotime("-$prev_months month")));
    $where3[$year][] = $month;
}
```

You can view the working example here:
http://ideone.com/UWI5wI

For reference, here are the examples of using your methodology vs the accepted norm:

```
// your last and 5
(month IN ('April', 'March', 'February', 'January') AND year = 2014) OR (month IN ('December') AND year = 2013)

// native 1 and 5
date <= 2014-05-01 01:00:00 AND date > 2013-12-01 01:00:00
```

I used the first (which is not convention) because every month has a first.  You would want to use the last day of the target month, instead of the first day of the following month, but you get that.

The difference is much more apparent when spanning LONG periods of time:

```
// 2 years, yours
(month IN ('April', 'March', 'February', 'January') AND year = 2014) OR (month IN ('December', 'November', 'October', 'September', 'August', 'July', 'June', 'May', 'April', 'March', 'February', 'January') AND year = 2013) OR (month IN ('December', 'November', 'October', 'September', 'August', 'July', 'June', 'May') AND year = 2012)

// The conventional way is still just two comparators...
```

Comment: Yes, I know thats why I am asking for suggestions.

Comment: You made me work for this.  I am sure I just solved your homework or something, but that was a neat little problem to solve.  So, despite that, "Thanks."

Answer (score 0):

the MySQL date format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

or (to get the date format for one month ago):

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("-1 month"));
```

You should be issuing a created (timestamp/datetime) column on new data, and simply searching through this data.

By creating month, day, year columns and trying to separate it you have only made this harder on yourself.

Comment: Good observation, that's why I said he should be using the date format :p Separating out columns the way OP did is simply horrible practice. The amount of code you had to write to solve this poor architecture speaks of itself.

Comment: It does, but TBH, I found it kind of interesting.  In much the same way as it is interesting to pull ones head from between railings.  You shouldn't do it, you would highly advise against it.  But the satisfaction of defeating it...  Meh, kind of worth it.

Comment: haha touche. i will say i'm quite impressed with your answer though :p in fact i'm throwing you an upvote.

Comment: You want to know the truth?  I work with a framework on a daily basis that does something not TOO unlike the above.  Doesn't have to do with `date`s, but it has gotten me very adept at procedurally creating complex `SELECT` statements for the otherwise trivial.  Keeps the heart beating.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your table structure you can use what you have as this:

```
$month = date('F', strtotime('-6 month'));
$year = date('Y', strtotime('-6 month'));
```

Will get you November and 2013

Not sure what type of data you are storing but another option may be to name your tables based on the year and then have columns for each month

table name: year_2014

```
 id----m1---m2---m3 etc...
 1----hello
 2----hi
 3----Hey
```

Then your query would be:

```
$month = date("n", strtotime('-6 month'));
$year = date('Y', strtotime('-6 month'));
$monthval = "m" + $month;
$SQL = "SELECT " . $monthval . " FROM year_".$year;

SELECT m11 FROM year_2013
```

Comment: What? Note sure that will work like you think it will, considering you are referencing non-existent tables, as well as columns...

Comment: Why would the tables etc... be non-existent since he would be creating them?

Comment: The OP has provided the table structure, do you see a column of name `m11`, and would it make sense to create a new table every year (`FROM year_2013`)?  Further, your example would require, not only a new table every year, but 12 columns, for...  A single string.  Would require filtering of `NULL` returns, etc.  Not going to be practical.  If the OP could modify table structure at will, the most ideal solution would be to utilize MySQL `date` or a Unix Timestamp.  But they are reluctant to do that for their own reasons.

Comment: But he is also asking for ideas and concepts, that's what this is.

Comment: I do not mean to sound rude, just frank: "From a data integrity perspective, this is not stable.  From a data storage perspective, this is inefficient (depending on column type) and inflexible (only one string of data per month [what if the OP needs more, like authors, tags, etc?]).  From a convention perspective, I have never seen this used.  From a usability perspective, this is hard to manage and debug (due to the previous statements)."  It is an idea, it is.

Comment: If the data is simple, this works just fine and is stable and efficient. If the data needs more complexity, then you probably wouldn't want to use this. But it really depends on the data the OP wants to store.

Comment: We seem to be having a disconnect here. Either I am missing something, or your explanation is incomplete. I am not sure which.