# how to fetch columns from multiple tables using sql

Tags: mysql

I am working on railway transport. 
I have the following tables:

**DAY table**

```
| - id  |  name  |
|   1   | sunday |
|   2   | monday |
|   3   | tuesday|
```

**station table**

```
|- id   | name  | 
|   1   | zaria |
|   2   | kano  |
|   3   | minna |
```

**route table**

```
| - id  | source_station_id | destination_station_id|
|   1   |       1           |            2          |
|   2   |       1           |            3          |
|   3   |       2           |            3          |
|   4   |       3           |            2          |
|   3   |       3           |            1          |
```

**departure table**

```
| route_id | day_id | departure_time |
|     1    |   2    |   07:00 hrs    |
|     1    |   3    |   07:00 hrs    |
|     3    |   2    |   15:30 hrs    |
```

`route_id, day_id, source_station_id, destination_station_id` are all foreign keys referenced from route, day, and station table respectively.

Now... how do I use sql to fetch from these tables..
output to look like the table below.

```
| source | destination | day | departure_time |
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    source.name      AS source,
    destination.name AS destination,
    day.name         AS day, 
    departure.time   AS departure_time
FROM departure
JOIN station AS source
    ON departure.source_station_id = source.id
JOIN station AS destination
    ON departure.source_station_id = destination.id
JOIN day
    ON departure.day_id = day.id
WHERE
    # any specific criteria you may have, like:
    departure.day_id = 1 # for a sunday
```

Should do it.  For more information see [MySQL JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

That said, this is a pretty standard question, and I would not be surprised to see it get voted down.

Further, from a structural point of view, you would really be better off storeing the "day" as a `DATETIME`, and converting this to and from a Human Readable date string on the fly.

As it stands, since you are only doing the day of the week, you have no way of differentiating between this week and last or last year. Have a look at the bottom-half of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689764/how-to-fetch-previous-months-data-from-database-in-php/23689822#23689822), where I start talking about spanning periods of time, and discuss the use of `DATETIME`.  Using native data-types is a preferable, both for performance, and ease of use.